# How to install any new software on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: package-management

Every time I try to install new software or get updates I get errors saying the package list can not be opened.When I look for a package in a terminal it says it can't be found?

Comment: Umm... We're gonna need more information than that. What, pray tell, are you trying to install?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried to update in the terminal? Try codes below see if this helps.
(Bring terminal up)
CTL+ALT+T

"sudo apt-get -f install"

"sudo apt-get update"

"sudo apt-get upgrade"

"sudo apt-get autoclean"

Comment: You can comment, so I'd recommend you remake this as a comment. Also, put code into a code block by selecting it and pressing `ctrl` + `k`.

Comment: Dnrdevil thank you so much this was the solution to all the problems I was having, so happy.